# How to display headers bold?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Is there a way to change the headers in XeLaTeX? Basically I just want my headers (pagenumber, author and title) to be bold, but none of the solutions suggested for LaTeX seems to have any effect on the headers. Is it because I'm using XeLaTeX? Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries \thepage}
\fancyhead[CO]{Titleoftext \bfseries}
\fancyhead[CE]{\bfseries Authoroftext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works fine except `\fancyhead[CO]{Titleoftext \bfseries}
`. You should write `\fancyhead[CO]{\bfseries Titleoftext}`. Otherwise `\bfseries` has no effect.

Comment: It does nothing with XeTeX.

Comment: No clue if this is your problem, but in addition to `\pagestyle{fancy}` you need to issue `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\maketitle` and every chapter. See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39330).

Comment: @Thorsten: neither of both versions give me a bold header. it seems \bfseries has no effect 'cause I'm using XelaTex. Is this possible?

Comment: @rdhs: even if I add \thispagestyle{fancy} it doesn't change at all. no bold headers. Is this just me?

Comment: Are you setting a new font? Perhaps you are choosing one for which you do not have a bold family. If so, there would be indications in the log file.

Comment: @david Please complete your example. We need to have a minimal _working_ example to see what your problem is. Because when I'm completing your code to a working example I get bold text.

Answer (score 2):

If I add to your code snippet the missing parts it does what you want:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries \thepage}
\fancyhead[CO]{\bfseries Titleoftext }
\fancyhead[CE]{\bfseries Authoroftext}

\begin{document}
foo  \newpage bar

\end{document}
```

the file list:

```
*File List*
book.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fancyhdr.sty
***********
```

Comment: @Thorsten: it's similar to mine, except that I'm using {book} and xelatex. does this make any difference?

Comment: @david: I changed it to class `book` and it also works. Insert `\listfiles` and compare the file list of the log file

Comment: @david No, it doesn't. As Herbert says, there's no difference wheter you use the `article` or the `book` class.